# Is base64 encoded images better than regular images in an intranet?

Tags: javascript, html, image, performance, base64

In my company, we have an intranet, and our branding web files has maybe 20 **small** images (basically icons) in total and a bunch of js and css files. I want to try to optimize for performance fully. I've done all the basic tricks like minification and combining. But now for images, I want to know whats the best approach given that it's an intranet with fast internal download speeds (fast wan) and dual core i7 computers. Also its mainly 6 offices spread across canada and US.

I have an approach in mind, where I use a tool to automatically convert each image with base64 encoding, and then put those in js or css files. Then use the tool to stuff the css into the js file. Now I am left with 1 js file that has all the css and base64 strings and its around 350KB. Also since its 1 js file, it can be cached on the server side and client side.

Does anyone know whats the advantages and disadvantages of this, and what can be done to improve it more?

Thanks

Comment: don't put the css in the js, that will be slower than doing it "normally" because css gets applied before the body loads, and you don't want to wait for JS to ship+parse in that timeslot...

Comment: I understand that there is extra work involved with having the browser have to insert all the css code into the dom, but this means there is 1 less http get request, and with my i7 machines, i don't think there would be a difference that an end user would notice compared to loading an external css file.

Comment: http is very fast on a lan so there's no reason to strive for "1 less http get request". it's not about CPU, it's about the long-optimized rendering pipeline you're side-skirting, cause several additional page-layout steps that might even be noticable in a side-by-side. aside from that, you can't inject any/all CSS like that because it would break relative paths. dataURLs add 33% extra weight to each image, which probably negates the additional header packets compared to reg images. then there's the maintenance nightmare every theme adjustment... in short, consider if the scheme is worth it...

Comment: dataURLs don't cache, so you have to ship the whole image info each time instead of just a bounce (etag) or nothing at all (far-future _expires_) one cool thing about dataURLs is that they make it easy to save the page for offline viewing, if that matters...

Comment: @dandavis Isn't it the case that dataURL's don't cache if they are embedded in the HTML file, but in my case they are all contained in a JS file, and JS files can be cached in the server and client side.

Comment: browsers can cache more than just the view from the network; they can cache image dimensions, even appearance. but if you can't even look at what images you need until the js arrives and executes and adds the css and it parses and executes, then you can't have the images ready to go before the `</body>` hits. it's a fun topic, and i'm open to exciting results, but i don't expect much.

Comment: This sounds like a solution in search of a problem. 20 small images on an intranet site is *not* a problem that needs solving.

Comment: But what if the JS link is referenced in the <head> tag. Then assuming browsers render elements top to bottom, wouldn't it insert, parse, and use the CSS all while in the <head> tag before the browser gets to parse the <body> tag?

Comment: you could do that, but you're not supposed to put scripts in the head because that makes the user have to stare at a blank screen while they load. css in js or imgs in css is slower due to the same physics that makes importing `<link>`s faster than `@import`s. what you describe could be faster on a crappy network, but not on a good lan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20 images, the total size of 350KB in high speed intranet.

It looks you are spending more value of time on optimization in this particular case than it could benefit in the end result.

If you want to boil this down to a single http request, get a php file to convert them to base64 data urls and embed them in your source file.

You can use a JSON file and load it via JS too. There you will have the effect of late loading of images.

In my opinion the best in this case is plain `img` tags.

Answer (score 0):

using base64 isn't really going to compress your image, it just makes it so it's not dependant on a file.  It actually makes the image bigger.

A good way to save image space would be using a sprite sheet, and compress your images with an online image compressor.

I'd recommend just using the images themselves.  Maybe compress them if you must.

Comment: I am fine with the overall image size being 1.3 times bigger since the total image size is pretty small anyways. Also since its an intranet with i7 machines, download speeds are very fast, so the 1.3 times is pretty light. However I was wondering is it worth it for the lowered http get requests?

Comment: Personally I don't believe it is, the html will actually have a higher response time, but by the sounds of it for your system this may probably be a fraction of a second lol, so really depends on your preference of your file structure.

Comment: But also consider that, all the dataURL's are in a JS file, and the JS file can be cached on server and client side. Nothing is actually hardcoded on the HTML file except the reference to the JS file.

Comment: Don't quote me, but wouldn't the JS still have to render in the HTML (cached in a js file or not) which would still increase the page load for each image.  Opposed to having the images cached themselves, or in a sprite sheet.

Comment: Yes there is more worked involved to render, from the client side, but I think all that will run faster than a user can notice with these i7 machines.

Comment: you're putting too much thought into something that's not very beneficial in the long run, I'd stick with using the images themselves